# LESS parent selector for first parent

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

From documentation about [`changing selector order`](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature-changing-selector-order) we can see this example:

```
.header {
  .menu {
    border-radius: 5px;
    .no-borderradius & {
      background-image: url('images/button-background.png');
    }
  }
}
```

and result will be

```
.no-borderradius .header .menu {}
```

How to use *parent-selector* `&` to get selector `.header .menu.no-borderradius` without duplicating code:

```
ul {
    li {
        a {
            .active &,
            &:hover {
                 color: red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

will provide CSS

```
.active ul li a {color: red;}
```

but required result is

```
ul li.active a {color: red;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have put the `&` (parent selector) at the wrong place. It shouldn't be put after the selector, instead it should be before the `.`. Setting the `&` after the selector means the whole parent selector (from the topmost selector) will be appended at the end of the current selector instead of getting inserted before (which is what you need for `.header .menu.no-borderradius` or `ul li.active`.

```css
.header {
  .menu {
    border-radius: 5px;
    &.no-borderradius { /* here & is equal to .header .menu */
      background-image: url('images/button-background.png');
    }
  }
}

ul {
  li {
    &.active, /* here & is equal to ul li */
    &:hover {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Regarding the update to the question - it is **currently not possible to achieve** `ul li.active a` using the below structure as parent selector means the entire chain of selectors till the current level and not just the immediate parent. There is no way to just pick the immediate parent.

```
ul {
  li {
    a {
      .active &,
      &:hover {
        color: red;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The only option currently possible is to write it like below:

```
ul {
  li {
    &.active a,
    a:hover {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

There is an [**open feature request**](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1075) for parent selectors to have targets but there is no decision on by when this would be done.

Comment: Ok, but what if structure is `ul li a` and I want to add selector for `li`?

Comment: Do you mean it is like `ul { li { a { } } }` and you want to add say `.active` to `li`? If yes then just change the `a` selector to `&.active a`. If you are trying to add a class (or some other selector) to the `li` from within the `a` then it is not possible because the parent selector `&` always gets the full parent.

Comment: Yes, your answer is not what I was looking for, confused my self little bit. Will update question

Comment: @Justinas: Please check the update to my answer. In short, there is currently no way to achieve what you need with parent selector. You'd have to use variables which would become very messy.